# Reliance Netconnect in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: internet-connection

I have a Reliance ZTE modem and I am not able to connect it in ubuntu. ( I have tried most of the methods which come when I search in google. they didn't work). Please help.. (Remember I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and not any older version)

Comment: it will not work in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Hackaholic why doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Ubuntu system and insert the dongle. You may hear some kind of sound after detection of the dongle in the system.

look at the top right corner you may see the small network connection icon.

Click that icon and you will see a menu. Click the “New CDMA connection” option at the bottom of this drop down menu and it will take you the Network Management window.

Click the “Mobile Broadband” tab and then click Add. This will take you to the Dial-Up Connection Setup Wizard. Just follow the wizard and it will take hardly a minute. Your Device will be detected automatically, click on Continue.

After it go to top right corner you may see the small network connection icon > Network Connection > mobile broadband > reliance

Choose edit from right pane

Now you have to prvide username password given by reliance it is same as your 10 digit data card No. Provide #777 in dial up No.

save settings and try to connect.